Forming Cayley Graphs from Graph Automorphism Groups
I came over the following proposition that could serve as a modified converse to the claim that "all Cayley graphs are vertex transitive" while studying Cayley graphs.
If the automorphism group of a graph $G$ has a vertex-transitive subgroup $A$, and if every non-identity element of $A$ does not fix any vertex, then $G$ is a Cayley graph for $A$.
I wonder how the former claim could be proven, and would also like to know how one could rigorously show that certain vertex-transitive graphs, e.g., the Peterson Graph, may never be the Cayley graph of any group. Thanks for any help!

Yes, this is true and well-known, sometimes called Sabidussi's Theorem. This should help you find references (it's on Wikipedia for example). The proof is quite straightforward. It's easy to show that, for every pair of vertices $u$ and $v$, there is a unique $a\in A$ mapping $u$ to $v$. So fix a vertex $u$, then label the vertices according to the group elements mapping $u$ to that vertex. That labels the vertex set with $A$, then look at the neighbourhood of the identity to recover the connection set, and check that everything works out.
